# Jenkins pipeline not creating workspace folders when other pipelines are

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am creating a new Pipeline on an existing, functioning Jenkins server.

At the moment it is a simple multibranch pipeline with the `Jenkinsfile`, and a `deploy.yml`

The issue is that the workspace folder is not being generated.

When I do `ls /var/lib/jenkins/workspace` I get a list of all the other deploy jobs that have created workspaces, and a `workspace.txt` file where I can see the names of the workspaces that SHOULD have been created, but there is no folder for that workspace.

If I do `mkdir /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/expectedname` and `touch /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/expectedname/deploy.yml` and run it, it creates a workspace called `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/expectedname@tmp` which is empty, and puts the retreived files in the one i created. If I delete the @tmp folder, it works. but it breaks again without advance notice, and it isn't feasible to keep having to create the fodler manually.

### Jenkinsfile

```groovy
#!groovy


node {
    currentBuild.displayName = "${env.BRANCH_NAME}-${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
    config = readYaml file: "${WORKSPACE}/deploy.yml"
}

pipeline {
    agent any

    
    stages {
        stage ('Fiddling'){

            steps {
                echo "***************** TAG: ${config.scm.tag} *****************"

            }
        }
    }
}
```

### deploy.yml

```yaml
env:
  wwwroot: "/var/www/siteroot"
  type: "test"
  ssh:
    servername: "mysecretserver.url"
    username: "jenkins"
conf:
  siteTitle: "Site Title"
  siteFQDN: "site.subdomain.domain.tld"
  defaultFromEmail: "test@domain.tld"
  sessionname: "SessionName"
  mysql:
    host: "localhost"
    database: "mycooldb"
    username: "dbuser"
    password: "s3cret"
scm:
  tag: "v.1.2"
```

### jenkins log

> ```
> 15:28:41  Started by user JoSSte
> 15:28:41   > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
> 15:28:41  Setting origin to git@bitbucket.org:t******/****.git
> 15:28:41   > git config remote.origin.url git@bitbucket.org:t******/****.git # timeout=10
> 15:28:41  Fetching origin...
> 15:28:41  Fetching upstream changes from origin
> 15:28:41   > git --version # timeout=10
> 15:28:41   > git --version # 'git version 2.17.1'
> 15:28:41   > git config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10
> 15:28:41  using GIT_SSH to set credentials YYYYYY
> 15:28:41   > git fetch --tags --progress -- origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
> 15:28:42  Seen branch in repository origin/master
> 15:28:42  Seen branch in repository origin/noscm
> 15:28:42  Seen branch in repository origin/stable
> 15:28:42  Seen branch in repository origin/working
> 15:28:42  Seen 4 remote branches
> 15:28:44  Obtained Jenkinsfile from 5374b39f33bf6ye904134e845d60fae76a97bb09
> 15:28:44  Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
> 15:28:44  [Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
> 15:28:44  [Pipeline] node
> 15:28:44  Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/tc-d-tr_noscm
> 15:28:44  [Pipeline] {
> 15:28:44  [Pipeline] readYaml
> 15:28:44  [Pipeline] }
> 15:28:44  [Pipeline] // node
> 15:28:44  [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
> 15:28:44  java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/tc-d-tr_noscm/deploy.yml does not exist.
> 15:28:44      at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.conf.ReadYamlStep$Execution.doRun(ReadYamlStep.java:113)
> 15:28:44      at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.AbstractFileOrTextStepExecution.run(AbstractFileOrTextStepExecution.java:32)
> 15:28:44      at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
> 15:28:44      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> 15:28:44      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> 15:28:44      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> 15:28:44      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> 15:28:44      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> 15:28:44  Finished: FAILURE
> ```

Why is this job failing when all the others are not? - the only thing I can see different is that the other jobs I have don't use `readYaml`

## Update

I made a new repo, with basically the same structure, without `readYaml`, on the same jenkins server - this hasn't failed  in the same way - I will try to ad that to it, and see if it breaks...

Comment: Does your Jenkins has a master and agent setup?

If yes both scripted with node {} and declarative with pipeline{} are running in different agent, that could be the reason you are not finding the workspace. 
I have just try to replicate your example in my jenkins master and I can see the Workspace